A film that ends with people sitting at a table near a lake and the land they are on separates and floats away with them into mist?
This question goes back a fair while, probably vey late 90's or early 2000's. I'm in Australia and a tv channel SBS screens a lot of strange films late at night. The scene described in the title is the last scene of the film.  A lot of people (I think dressed in old-style clothes, vintage) are all sitting at a table in a parkland next to a lake. The land that they are on separates from the rest of the land and floats away into mist on the water, they continue with their picnic unconcerned.
Now this is where the question gets a bit more complex, I had fallen asleep while watching the film and I'm unsure whether this ending was for the film I was watching when I fell asleep or not. If it isn't, then getting the names of both films would be fantastic.
The film I was watching prior to falling asleep involved a group of people living in underground shelters due to some world ending event. I think it may have been European with subtitles. The people were making munitions for the man who ran the shelter. He actually lived topside where life was continuing as normal and was rich from selling the munitions being made. Someone (possibly a child/teen) finds a way out and leaves. The rich owner sends someone after the escapee so they can't return to tell the others that they are being lied to.
The channel SBS screens foreign language films (my natural language is English) with subtitles regularly so they may not be English speaking films.

The film is Emir Kusturicas Underground 
Details see Wikipedia and IMDB.
The film is available at Youtube:

Part 1
Part 2

The end scene you mention can be found at 



Full respect mate, legendary response, consider me satisfied :)

LOL!  I was thinking of asking a question about identifying this same film, also seen on SBS long ago.  ..It's a small Oz.  ;)
